# Detect Phone State OnCreate

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I'm making an app that need to detect phone call onCreate. If a phone call is received, my app has to hide in the background. I used PhoneStateListener. However, it only activates when there is a phone status change.

How can I detect phone status on onCreate function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For incoming calls we need to use the TelephonyManager class and its method listen to register a listener that will receive call state, data connection, network, SIM, and other events related to telephony. We are interested only in the call state notifications. This requires android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE permission.

So, create our listener class derived from PhoneStateListener, and override the onCallStateChanged method, as follows:

```
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.telephony.PhoneStateListener;
import android.telephony.TelephonyManager;
import android.util.Log;

public class PhoneState extends Service {
    private CallStateListener mCallStateListener = new CallStateListener();
    private TelephonyManager mTelephonyManager;
    private int mCallState;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    mTelephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
    mCallState = mTelephonyManager.getCallState();
    mTelephonyManager.listen(mCallStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        Log.d("onDestroy", "onDestroy");
    mTelephonyManager.listen(mCallStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_NONE);
    super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null; //-- not a bound service--
    }

    private final class CallStateListener extends PhoneStateListener {
    @Override
    public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

        switch (mCallState) {

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                    Log.d("state", "idle --> off hook = new outgoing call");
                    // idle --> off hook = new outgoing call
                    //triggerSenses(Sense.CallEvent.OUTGOING);
                } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    Log.d("state", "idle --> ringing = new incoming call");
                    // idle --> ringing = new incoming call
                    //triggerSenses(Sense.CallEvent.INCOMING);
                }
                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    Log.d("state", "off hook --> idle  = disconnected");
                    // off hook --> idle  = disconnected
                    //triggerSenses(Sense.CallEvent.ENDED);
                } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING) {
                    Log.d("state", "off hook --> ringing = another call waiting");
                    // off hook --> ringing = another call waiting
                    //triggerSenses(Sense.CallEvent.WAITING);
                }
                Log.d("CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK", String.valueOf(state));
                break;

            case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
                    Log.d("state", "ringing --> off hook = received");
                    // ringing --> off hook = received
                    //triggerSenses(Sense.CallEvent.RECEIVED);
                } else if (state == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE) {
                    Log.d("state", "ringing --> idle = missed call");
                    // ringing --> idle = missed call
                    //triggerSenses(Sense.CallEvent.MISSED);
                }
                break;
        }

        mCallState = state;
    }
    }

    public static void init(Context c) {
        c.startService(new Intent(c, PhoneState.class));
    Log.d("Service enabled","Service enabled: " + true);
    }
}
```

In your main Activity you just start the Phonestate service as,

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;

public class SpinnerSample extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    PhoneState.init(getBaseContext());
    }
}
```

When you uninstall the application it will automatically stopped your service. Other wise it will detect the phone call either the application is active nor inactive.

Comment: How can I get the phone state when application launch?

Comment: Hi Tan i modified the code. Please check and let me know. Thanks

Comment: Isn't it sufficient to just retrieve the state from the TelephonyManager? E.g. TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE); return tm.getCallState();

Comment: Hi Jeba, thanks for this answer, seems to be exactly what i need. 

IDE: Android Studio
Testing: on physical phone

Am having an issue though. 

While the "Service enabled" log shows okay (the init function), the other log notifications don't show (in onCallStateChanged).

Checked with some logging at the start of the onCallStateChanged function, and verified it's not getting called at all (testing by calling the phone from another phone).

To debug what's happening, am wondering if you have any pointers?

Comment: Never mind! Was missing the <service></service> call in the AndroidManifest.xml file.

Answer (score 0):

It has two steps.Firstly,you should have a listener that extends PhoneStateListener.When phone state changes,it will touch onCallStateChanged.The phone has three states :CALL_STATE_RINGING,
CALL_STATE_IDLE and CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK.You can detect these states.Secondly,as you say,it also  needs broadcastreceiver.You can hide your APP in the background.
Last but not least,don't forget register receiver and read phone state permission in AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Sorry, I stated wrongly. I used PhoneStateListener, it does listen to the phone states, but What I want is when the app is open, it has to detect whether the phone is calling. PhoneStateListener doesn't trigger when the app is open, only when the phone state changed.